# How to add/insert a xml node into text

Tags: xml, delphi, openoffice.org, openoffice-writer

I am generating a text document in the open document format (odt) which is based on XML.
But I have a problem when adding a tabulator in a text passage.
When I create it in the Open Office application and save the document the passage has the internal XML representation as:

```
<text:p text:style-name="P5">Prepared by: <text:tab/>Tim Test</text:p>
```

When generating it automatically I come to this part in my source code:

```
   Node, Node1: IXMLNode;
   ...
   Node := Node1.AddChild('text:p');
   Node.Attributes['text:style-name'] := 'P5';
   Node.Text := 'Prepared by: Tim Test';
```

But I can't find any method to add the  node into the text before "Tim", or at least not with the internal Delphi XML library.

Is there a way to achieve it or is there any other Delphi XML library which can do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keep in mind that XML is a hierarchy of nodes, including text snippets.  The XML you showed looks like this in a tree:

```
[element] 'text:p'
  │
  ├─[attributes]
  │   │
  │   └─[attribute] 'text:style-name'
  │       │
  │       └─[text] 'PS'
  │
  └─[children]
      |
      ├─[text] 'Prepared by: '
      │
      ├─[element] 'text:tab'
      │ 
      └─[text] 'Tim Test'
```

That should help you visualize how you have to add nodes to your document to get the desired output, eg:

```
Node, Node1, Node2: IXMLNode;
...
Node := Node1.AddChild('text:p');
Node.Attributes['text:style-name'] := 'P5';

Node2 := Node.OwnerDocument.CreateNode('Prepared by: ', ntText);
Node.ChildNodes.Add(Node2);

Node2 := Node.OwnerDocument.CreateElement('text:tab', '');
Node.ChildNodes.Add(Node2);

Node2 := Node.OwnerDocument.CreateNode('Tim Test', ntText);
Node.ChildNodes.Add(Node2);
```

Comment: After I changed: 
`Node1 := Node.OwnerDocument.CreateElement('text:tab');`
to
`Node1 := Node.OwnerDocument.CreateElement('text:tab','');`
it worked perfect!

Comment: +1. Excellent answer, particularly the illustration. Nice, Remy. :-)