# Delphi XML Add node

Tags: xml, delphi, save, edit

I have a question about writing settings to an xml file.

I'm reading some data from an XML file with my Delphi application like this:

```
    procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    var
      i: Integer;
    begin
      Doc := LoadXMLDocument('Programs.xml');
      Data := Doc.DocumentElement;
      NumberOfFilesToCheck:=Data.ChildNodes.Count-1;
      for i := 0 to NumberOfFilesToCheck do
      begin
        Node:=Data.ChildNodes[i];
        SourceFileName[i]:=Node.ChildNodes['file'].Text;
        SourceDir[i]:=Node.ChildNodes['dir'].Text;
        SourceDirOrFile[i]:=Node.ChildNodes['dirfile'].Text;
        SourceName[i]:=Node.ChildNodes['name'].Text;
   ...
      end;
```

The XML looks like this:

```
<data>
<program>
    <file>C:\Users\MarcelS\Desktop\Software\MRS\MCUMini\CAN_IO_G_MCUMini_v3.1\user_code.c</file>
    <dir>C:\Users\MarcelS\Desktop\Software\Versiebeheer\MRS\MCUMini\</dir>
    <dirfile>dir</dirfile>
    <name>MCUMini_v3.1</name>
</program>
<program>
 <file>C:\Users\MarcelS\Desktop\Software\MRS\ControlRPM\CAN_IO_G_Control_RPM_v1.3_0001\user_code.c</file>
    <dir>C:\Users\MarcelS\Desktop\Software\Versiebeheer\MRS\Control RPM\</dir>
    <dirfile>dir</dirfile>
    <name>ControlRPM_v1.3</name>
</program>
</data>
```

Now I want to be able to add a new 'program' to the xml and save it. I made some edit boxes where I can write the new data.
I'm not sure how to do this.
Can anyone help with a short example?
I cannot find one on the internet which I understand...

Thank you in advance!

Marcel

Comment: A simple search here for [delphi add nodes to XML](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdelphi%5D+add+nodes+to+xml) can answer this question for you. Please do those sorts of searches before asking a new question, as chances are quite good that there is an existing answer here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add/insert a xml node into text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18646851/how-to-add-insert-a-xml-node-into-text)

Comment: I did search and found these examples, but it was not completely clear to me because they seemed a bit different from what I am searching. But could also be my lack of knowledge. I will take a look again, but a nice simple example is always very helpfull for me.